# Restore Value when validationFailed() PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a XHTML file which contains (partially) the following code:

```
  <p:dataTable widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar"
                             id="display"
                             value="#{usersBean.users}"
                             var="u"
                             paginator="true"
                             rows="10"
                             filteredValue="#{usersBean.filteredUsersList}"
                             editable="true"
                             editMode="cell"
                             rowKey="#{u.id}"
                             selectionMode="single">
                    <p:ajax
                            event="cellEdit"
                            listener="#{allUsersBean.onCellEdit}"
                            update=":form:growl"/>
```

now when a user tries to change a field but the new value is invalid (take for example, if an E-Mail Address is already in the system, and the user tries to enter an email address which is already registered), the original value (the initial value) should be replaced back into the cell.

Example: **User A** has the E-Mail Address *a@example.com* in system, he logs in and tries to change his E-Mail Address, he enters *b@example.com*, but this Address is already registered in the system and its associated with **User B**, so this is an invalid input, and the cell should again display the old value (in this case E-Mail Address), which is *a@example.com*.

In my backing bean I'll throw

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
```

when the newly entered E-Mail Address is found in system, but this doesn't restore the intial value.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tried putting the old value back in the model?

Comment: I am saving the old value in a variable called ```initialUser```, but there is no set method to put it back into the model.

In this method ```public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent<User> event)```, event does not have any setOldValue or something similar.

Comment: How do you mean there is no set method? Didn't you write your own model?

Comment: My model does have setters and getters, I meant the event from primefaces does not have one.

Comment: Then reset the value in the listner

Comment: real validation should be done in a validator... Not in the backingbean/controller